# Javascript closures - how to prevent memory leaks

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures

I am trying to understand how I can prevent memory leaks when using closures in JavaScript.  Can someone let me know if what I am doing is correct?

I have a dummy function:

```
var testFunction = function(obj1){

   //other code..

   on(control, "click", function(){
         obj1.label= "test";
    });

 };
```

1) does the above cause a memory leak because obj1 is being referenced in the click event.?

2) can I fix it by doing the following:

```
 var testFunction = function(obj1){

      //other code.....

       on(control, "click", function(){
             var newObj1 = obj1;
             newObj1.label= "test";
             newObj1 = null;
        });


    };
```

If this is a poor example, can someone show me better example of a closure with memory leak and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both functions will not work. (Well, the functions will work, but the event handlers will fail.)

Comment: Thanks, I took out the line where I had set obj1 = null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to understand how I can prevent memory leaks when using closures in JavaScript.

You hardly never need to. The engine's garbage collector does that for you. It's pretty powerful, and rarely needs help.

> does the above cause a memory leak because obj1 is being referenced in the click event.?

It does prevent `obj1` from being garbage-collected, yes, because you still reference it. However, this does not qualify as a "memory *leak*", because it is intentional. You *want* to preserve the object in memory.

It might become a leak if `testFunction` is called more frequently than you expected, and if `on` does preserve the closure longer than needed.

> can I fix it by doing the following

a) there's nothing to fix b) no, introducing an extra variable does not alter the behaviour. `obj1` is still referenced from the closure.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what qualifies as a memory leak because I do want to preserve the object.